# Is there any way to have AltGr behave as a regular Alt when used in combination with non-character keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I frequently need to type characters accessible with the AltGr key, but having that key as an ISO_Level3_Shift makes it unusable in applications for keyboard shortcuts. Ideally, I'd like both Alt keys to act as an ISO_Level3_Shift (makes it easier to type characters that are typed with the right hand), and retain their function as a modifier in applications.

In short, what I'd like to achieve is this:

- Either Alt key + any character key = alternative characters
- Either Alt used in combination with any other key = Alt is regular Alt

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, your idea is inspiring, but what if the user wants to use an Alt+alphanumeric shortcut?